# Include YAML, not frontmatter, in output from knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to use knitr to generate a Markdown document. In that Markdown document, I'd like to include some YAML that is generated by a separate program. However, inserting that text as a plain YAML is conflated with the standard frontmatter part of a knitr document. I'm unsure how to escape the YAML that is intended to be in the Markdown output.

That is, the knitr document would follow something like:

```r
---
output: github_document
---
---
foo: bar
---

Lorem Ipsum
```

Would generate a corresponding Markdown file:

```
---
foo: bar
---

Lorem Ipsum
```

Within the knitr document, have tried a few ways to escape the `---`, including:

`\---` which outputs as `\-–` (en-dash em-dash)
`\-\-\-` outputs as `\---`
`-\--` outputs as `\---`

Comment: have u tried putting into a chunk and using `results='asis'`

Comment: This was very helpful and was the best solution for my particular problem. Thank you.

Comment: `github_document` will use the `gfm` markdown variant from pandoc. It means it will output a document using Github Flavored Markdown, and GFM does not support to have YAML blocks in its content. So you won't be able to generate the expected markdown file if you are using `github_document`. If you are looking for another markdown variant, there is the `md_document()` format.

Answer (score 4):

`````
---
title: "show asis yaml header"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/28/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

````markdown
---
title: "show asis yaml header"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/28/2020"
output: html_document
---
````
`````

You want to have a `markdown` chunk to show your yaml header. it renders to HTML like this

[image]